# Paperboy throwing error: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, airflow

I have installed **paperboy** using steps given at https://github.com/timkpaine/paperboy.git

and executed using

```sh
python3 -m paperboy
```

while uploading notebook from UI

[image]

when click on the save button UI not responding but throwing below error on console

> ```
> CRITICAL:root:list : <class 'paperboy.storage.sqla.models.report.ReportSQL'>, result : 0 - 0
> [2019-12-03 15:26:01 +0530] [24991] [ERROR] Error handling request /api/v1/notebooks?action=save
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
>     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 176, in handle_request
>    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/falcon/api.py", line 244, in __call__
>     responder(req, resp, **params)
>  File "/home/exa00112/xstream/paperboy/paperboy/resources/notebook.py", line 21, in on_post
>    resp.body = json.dumps(self.db.notebooks.store(req.context['user'], req.params, self.session))
>  File "/home/exa00112/xstream/paperboy/paperboy/storage/sqla/notebook.py", line 44, in store
>     notebook = nbformat.writes(strip_outputs(nbformat.reads(params.get('file').file.read(), 4)))
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nbformat/__init__.py", line 74, in reads
>     nb = reader.reads(s, **kwargs)
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nbformat/reader.py", line 58, in reads
>     nb_dict = parse_json(s, **kwargs)
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nbformat/reader.py", line 14, in parse_json
>     nb_dict = json.loads(s, **kwargs)
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
>     s.__class__.__name__))
> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a master branch to install paperboy https://github.com/timkpaine/paperboy.git

```
git clone https://github.com/timkpaine/paperboy.git
cd paperboy
conda create --name python3.7 python=3.7
conda activate python3.7
npm install
npm run build
pip install -e .
```

then open

```
paperboy/server/deploy_nix.py
```

change line number 2 with

```
from six import iteritems #from gunicorn.six import iteritems
```

then run

```
python -m paperboy
```